# Settings for Open PHP/HTML/JS extension for localhost on a Mac - Cataline 15.5

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

Could anyone please advise on the correct settings for "Open PHP/HTML/JS" on a Mac running Catalina 15.5
I have 2 test files in my Sites folder in a folder PHP_Test , index.php and info.php, Whatever settings I put for "Open PHP/HTML/JS" it always produces the same file path in the browser (usually Chrome but not always) namely /Users/john/Sites/PHP_Test/info.php for example and the file is not parsed in the browser just the file text.

If I remove the DocumentRoot stuff and add localhost i.e. localhost/PHP_Test/info.php the file is parsed as it should be.

Could anyone please advise what settings I should be using? I have tried every permutation I could think of and also none always with exactly the same result as though settings are completely ignored and a file default not localhost is being used.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually figured it out.

Two things. Although Apache seemed set up OK and a few basic tests worked OK it wasn't at all! Mac updates always seem to trash Apache and PHP setup for novices like me. The online article [Coolest Guides](http:////https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/install-apache-mysql-php-on-macos-catalina-10-15/) does a great detailed job of the full setup and there were quite a few issues that needed resolving. So look there and check first even if your issue at first like mine doesn't seem to be directly related.

When set up my localhost was set for access in the form

```
    http : //localhost/~username
```

Replace username with your own user. The site root is thus the folder

```
    Users/username/Sites
```

which is essentially referenced as ~username via

```
    http : // localhost/~username
```

Experts will probably express it better and more correctly than I have here.

After quite a bit of experimentation I came up with the following settings that worked for my needs in the VS Code Open PHP/HTML/JS extension. As follows:

**Open-PHP-HTML-JS-in-browser: Custom Url To Open**

http : //localhost/~username/${workspaceFolderBasename}/${relativeFile}

**Open-PHP-HTML-JS-in-browser: Document Root Folder**

http : //localhost/~username/

**Open-PHP-HTML-JS-in-browser: Url To Open**
custom

I tested with a PHP file buried several folders deep e.g.
finally resolved to

```
       http : //localhost/~username/Test/Test2/test.php
```

and the extension opens the file in the browser.